# static and non-static error

Tags: java, static

```
public class B extends A{
    public int g(){
        int x = super.x;
        int y = super.getOne();
        return x+y;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(g());
    }
}
```

Why do I get the error (on the left of the printing line):

> cannot make a static reference to the non-static method g() from the type B

?

Comment: You get that error because you cannot make a static reference to the non-static method g() from the type B.

Comment: create an object for B

Answer (score 0):

Because you can not access non-static method in a static context - in this case main method.

This will work:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.g());
}
```

You have to create an instance of B class in that static main method and then call `g()`;

Answer (score 0):

you cant directly invoke non static methods like this you have to make a object out of class B and then use the method g() for that object.